# grep for a line with a specific words

Tags: shell, unix, grep

I have a file  Batman.txt:

```
Batman lives in Gotham City.
In Gotham city batman is a vigilante
Gotham city has many criminals.
Batman and Joker live in Gotham city.
Superman and batman are very friendly, but batman is always prepared for 
bad events unlike superman.
Superman lives in Metropolis city.
Batman has visited Metropolis city a couple of times.
```

I want to separate the lines that have batman and Gotham and city in the same line. That is:

```
Batman lives in Gotham City.
In Gotham city batman is a vigilante
Batman and Joker live in Gotham city.
```

So far I have this :

```
grep -E -i "batman|gotham|city" batman.txt
```

But it doesnt provide the necessary output. I get other lines which are not required.

The out put is :

```
Batman lives in Gotham City.
In Gotham city batman is a vigilante
Gotham city has many criminals.
Batman and Joker live in Gotham city.
Superman and batman are very friendly, but batman is always prepared for 
Superman lives in Metropolis city.
Batman has visited Metropolis city a couple of times.
```

Please help. 
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `grep -P` and lookahead regex since your keywords can appear in any order:

```
grep -iP '(?=.*?\bbatman\b)(?=.*?\bcity\b)(?=.*?\bgotham\b)' file
Batman lives in Gotham City.
In Gotham city batman is a vigilante
Batman and Joker live in Gotham city.
```

Or using awk:

```
awk '/[bB]atman/&&/[cC]ity/&&/[gG]otham/' file
Batman lives in Gotham City.
In Gotham city batman is a vigilante
Batman and Joker live in Gotham city.
```

Comment: Both your answers are correct :/ I will give @shiplu the right answer. only because you have a lot of Points lol

Comment: It is your decision but I will avoid using multiple piped `grep` for such a simple task. Imagine if you have 10 keywords then you are going to need 10 piped `grep` commands. If you want to avoid lookahead `awk` is the right command to use here.

Comment: Hey @anubhava 
What do I do if I want to ignore a few words ? 
for example : if I want to ignore the sentence with joker in it?
How do I add that ?
Also could you explain what does `\b` do ?  :)

Comment: You can use: `awk '/[bB]atman/&&/[cC]ity/&&/[gG]otham/&&!/joker/' file` And `/` is used for regex delimiter in awk.

Comment: could you also give me the grep approach ? :) 
I tried 
`grep -iP'(?=.*?\bbatman\b)(?=.*?\bcity\b)(?=.*?\bgotham\b)(^=.*^\bjoker\b)' batman.txt`

Comment: You can use: `grep -iP '(?=.*?\bbatman\b)(?=.*?\bcity\b)(?=.*?\bgotham\b)(?!.*?\bjoker\b)' batman.txt`

Comment: Last request : Do you have any books or websites where I could learn these commands? I would really appreciate it if you could suggest some :)

Comment: This is basically learning about regex and best site I know is http://regular-expressions.info

Answer (score 2):

Why didn't you try piping to another grep?

```
grep -iw batman file | grep -iw gotham | grep -iw city
```

Its much simpler. You dont even need to learn regex for this.

Comment: `-w` is `exact word match`